# How can I delete duplicate rows in the same table that have identical CLOB data?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table in Oracle of which one of the columns (named `CONTENTSTRING`) is a `CLOB`. However, some of the rows in this table have identical data in this column. What I'd like to do is remove all the rows except for one that have this identical data. How can I accomplish this?

Googling around, I see a ton of examples for comparing two columns. I also see examples comparing between two different tables. What I don't see is an example using one table and just comparing the rows! I do think I might need to use this function: `dbms_lob.compare`. However, I'm still not sure how I can set this function up.

From a programmer's perspective, I would think maybe I should do something like:

```
SELECT CONTENTSTRING FROM TABLE_ALPHA A
```

and then somehow do another select from the same table as `TABLE_ALPHA B`, and then use `dmbs_lob.compare` to compare the two columns. If the row numbers are different AND the column contents are equal, then the row from `TABLE_ALPHA B` can be deleted.

I think that's the right approach, but how exactly would I write this out in Oracle using SQL? I would appreciate any help or resources on this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a primary key in the table ? If yes what's the column name ? It would be good if you could edit your answer to add sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM TABLE_ALPHA A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_ALPHA B
  WHERE DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(A.CONTENTSTRING, B.CONTENTSTRING) = 0
  AND A.ROWID > B.ROWID
)
```

This deletes all dublicates except first one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to use this query to accomplish what I needed! I added a condition in each select statement to limit the number of rows to compare as well, since the query takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you have a primary key field in the source table (I called it `id`).

You can use a subquery to list the `id`s of the duplicated records : this works by self-joining the table with `dbms_lob.compare` and a comparison clause on the `id`. If duplicate rows exist with the same CLOB content, all `id`s *but* the most ancient (ie the smallest) are selected. The outer query just deletes the selected `id`s. The `NVL` will consider `NULL` contents as duplicates (if that's not relevant for your use case, just remove them).

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_ALPHA 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT b.id
    FROM TABLE_ALPHA a
    INNER JOIN TABLE_ALPHA b 
        ON  
        (
            (a.contentString IS NULL AND b.contentString IS NULL) 
            OR dbms_lob.compare(a.CONTENTSTRING, b.CONTENTSTRING) = 0
        ) 
        AND b.id > a.id
);
```

See [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=63bd27f56a1bb2fb866bcc772ce334db).

Comment: This will consider a `NULL` value and a string `'Null'` to be identical; which should not be true. Better would be to compare for `NULL` using `((a.contentString IS NULL AND b.contentString IS NULL) OR DBMS_LOB.COMPARE( a.contentString, b.contentString ) = 0)`.

Comment: @MT0 : that's an edge case, but you are right, thanks for pointing this out I updated the query (and the fiddle)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up using Vladimir's solution, as I ended up needing to use row.id. I appreciate you looking into this for me!